# I started a docker container in bluemix and ice ps shows my container in state "Queued" for hours

Tags: docker, queue, ibm-cloud

I started a docker container in bluemix with a postgres images I uploaded on my own. The docker container stayed in state "Queued" for hours now. Here is what I did:

// upload the latest postgres image to the bluemix repository

ice cpi postgres:9.5 ansi/postgres:9.5

// start the docker container in bluemix

ice run --name=tinydatabase -m 512 registry.ng.bluemix.net/ansi/postgres:9.5

When I look up my containers with "ice ps" the just started container is in state "Queued" for hours now. Is there anything wrong I did? I could not find anything in the bluemix documentation at all about the state.

Comment: Hi, could you pull and start this container locally? If so you could retrieve the container logs using ice logs command

Comment: I could start the container locally without any problem. "logs" is not responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an internal server error in bluemix. I contacted the support and they solved the problem by contacting local administrator guys.